# How to match a number in middle using python regular expression?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I am trying to put PASS/FAIL criteria for the following command output.

```
router-7F2C13#show app stats gmail on TEST/switch1234-15E8CC
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     APPLICATION           BYTES_IN         BYTES_OUT           NUM_FLOWS
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  gmail                0                 0                  0
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
router-7F2C13#
```

I need to match only "NUM_FLOWS". If its "zero" then it will be considering as FAIL. 
If its "Greater than or equal to 1" then it will be considering as PASS.

```
FAIL criteria example:
======================

router-7F2C13#show app stats gmail on TEST/switch1234-15E8CC
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     APPLICATION           BYTES_IN         BYTES_OUT           NUM_FLOWS
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  gmail                0                 0                  0
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
router-7F2C13#



PASS criteria example: (Greater than or equal to 1)
======================

router-7F2C13#show app stats gmail on TEST/switch1234-15E8CC
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     APPLICATION           BYTES_IN         BYTES_OUT           NUM_FLOWS
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  gmail                0                 0                  1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
router-7F2C13#
```

Please guide me on how to do this.

Comment: Have you tried to do something yourself?

Comment: You probably don't need regex for this. Just use the `str.split()` method on the target line and grab the last element of the resulting list.

Comment: @PM 2Ring.. Thanks for your comment. I am new to python. Could please tell me how to do this with split command.

Comment: Are these individual files?  Is the "gmail" line always the 5th line in the file?

Comment: @Mark Tolonen. Yes always it will be 5th line in that show command

Comment: @balu: Please see Mark Tolonen's answer. His script will process a file named on the command line, or if no file is named it will read from standard input, so you can pipe data to it, as per his example. See the docs for the `fileinput` module for details. Note that Mark's examples in the second code block is for Windows; you'd run it slightly differently on other OSes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NUM_FLOWS\n-+[\s\S]*?(\d+)\s*-+
```

You can try this.Grab the capture.

See demo.

https://www.regex101.com/r/bC8aZ4/7

```
x="""router-7F2C13#show app stats gmail on TEST/switch1234-15E8CC
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     APPLICATION           BYTES_IN         BYTES_OUT           NUM_FLOWS
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  gmail                0                 0                  0
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
router-7F2C13#
---------------------------------------------------------------
router-7F2C13#"""
if int(re.findall(r"NUM_FLOWS\n-+[\s\S]*?(\d+)\s*-+",x)[0]):
      print "pass"
else:
      print "fail"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But Its always printing as "PASS".  Could you please check this. It should print "FAIL", if its zero.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is command output you can pipe the output of the command into a Python script and process it with the `fileinput` module:

```
import fileinput
for line in fileinput.input():
    if fileinput.filelineno() == 5:
        # split the line on whitespace, and take the last item.
        x = int(line.split()[-1])
        print('PASS' if x else 'FAIL')
        break # so it won't process more lines past 5
```

Result with `pass.xxx` containing your pass criteria and `fail.xxx` containing your fail criteria:

```
c:\> type fail.xxx | check.py
FAIL

c:\> type pass.xxx | check.py
PASS
```